# Wordpress Validate Billing_Phone in User Admin Area

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, admin, backend

I currently have wordpress/woocommerce and a billing_phone valiation function (provided below) which works within the My Account -> Account Details, Checkout, etc. This function firstly checks if the value is a valid phone number, and then checks if that phone number already exists. This is a very important function in my plugin as I cannot afford to have duplicates.

I require the same checks/balances as the front end in the backend... Where I am having problems is in locating the most appropriate hook or group of hooks to allow me to validate the billing_phone field within the admin area and 1) Display the error using error message you would normally see in the admin backend, and 2) Not update the field and show the error.

I have tried `user_profile_update_errors` - alas it only provides the error AFTER it has updated the meta and I cannot find any information on how to include checks within the `$error` variable. I also tried `edit_user_profile_update` and `show_user_profile` but I don't know how to add errors to the below function.

```
function user_admin_validate_billing_phone() {

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && !empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) { 

        if ( !preg_match('/^04[0-9]{8}$/D', str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) ) {

        //  Error: Billing Phone Number is Invalid.

        }

        $existing_billing_phone = get_users( 'meta_value=' . str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        if ( !empty( $existing_billing_phone ) ) {

            if ( $current_user->billing_phone != str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {

            // Error: Billing Phone Number Already Exists.

            }
            else { 
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As stated, I have attempted the following hooks:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'user_admin_validate_billing_phone', 90 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'user_admin_validate_billing_phone', 90 );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'user_admin_validate_billing_phone' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'user_admin_validate_billing_phone' );
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors, 'user_admin_validate_billing_phone', 10, 3 );
```

...however either the error comes up and the fields still change, or I don't know how to carry over the appropriate error handling, eg:

```
$error = new WP_Error();
$error->add( 'error', __( 'Billing Mobile Phone Number already exists.' ) );
```

Any assistance, or guidance to the right process would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A example

```php
function validate_phone_field(&$errors, $update = null, &$user  = null) {
    if ( empty($_POST['billing_phone']) ) {
        $errors->add('empty_phone', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please Enter a phone number');
    }
}
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'validate_phone_field' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your input - I needed to make a few changes including my existing validations in the other hooks in to this one, and have this run simply for providing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code.

```
function user_admin_validate_billing_phone() {

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && !empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) { 

        if ( !preg_match('/^04[0-9]{8}$/D', str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) ) {

        //  Error: Billing Phone Number is Invalid.
            wc_add_notice(__('Billing Phone Number is Invalid.', 'woocommerce'));

        }

        $existing_billing_phone = get_users( 'meta_value=' . str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        if ( !empty( $existing_billing_phone ) ) {

            if ( $current_user->billing_phone != str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {

            // Error: Billing Phone Number Already Exists.
                wc_add_notice(__('Billing Phone Number Already Exists.', 'woocommerce'));

            }
            else { 
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: `wc_add_notice` creates function errors as this is intended for frontend woocommerce. It will not work in the `wp-admin/user-edit.php` user admin area.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wh_phoneValidateCheckoutFields');

function wh_phoneValidateCheckoutFields() {
    $billing_phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_phone');

    if (strlen(trim(preg_replace('/^[6789]\d{9}$/', '', $billing_phone))) > 0) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Invalid <strong>Phone Number</strong>, please check your input.'), 'error');
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin PHP files.

Please Note: By default WooCommerce use billing_phone field to take phone number, but if you have customized it then you can replace billing_phone with your field name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I require the functions for the wp-admin/user-edit.php (user admin backend). I believe `woocommerce_checkout_process` is for the frontend?